# How can I find UI designers for iPhone apps

Tags: interaction-design, iphone, gui-design

I am a software developer who likes to develop iPhone apps in his free time. I have found that being not very skilled (or maybe talented) in graphic design, it takes a lot of time to create the designs for the app that I could rather spend inventing something in the area where I am at home (i.e. the development).

I was thinking of partnering up with some guy(s) that would help me refine the design allowing me to concentrate on the rest. Obviously, having this as a hobby an being on a tight (almost non-existing) budget, the only thing I can offer is a part of the profit. So who I am looking for is not a freelancer, but more of a collaborator.

Where do you think I have the best shot trying my luck ?

Comment: So what type of graphics are you looking for? And what type of apps do you have? Are any in production?

Comment: @culvi The first one (iosapps.at/energytracker) was released 2 weeks ago, I'm now thinking about adding some features and redesigning it..

Comment: Regarding "the only thing I can offer is a part of the profit" you may find this question on a sister site very helpful: [Forming a new software startup, how do I allocate ownership fairly?](http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/6949/forming-a-new-software-startup-how-do-i-allocate-ownership-fairly)

Comment: If you're looking for a graphic designer, then you would be better off asking this on the graphic design stack exchange site, not the user experience site.

Comment: I've tried that, they closed my question and redirected me here, kinda hard to fit anywhere :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran across a site called [Build It With Me](http://www.builditwith.me/) a while back that may be worth looking in to.

Comment: That one's really interesting, seems the people there are really looking exactly for that kind of exchange. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're from Austria, right? I'd check the german speaking forums and communities. For example [www.dasauge.at/foren](http://www.dasauge.at/foren/) or [www.apfeltalk.de/forum](http://www.apfeltalk.de/forum/) (and I'm sure you find more of that kind).

Also: Try to be specific when you look for somebody; tell them what the project is about, sell it to them (but of course don't tell too much so it can't be copied easily).

Hope that helps, Phil

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with that!? Let me know what you have in your mind? I am running a small company and we can help you with that, about budget don't worry bring the stuff and then we will see? For starter check out the NaanMap for iPhone